# Convert String to BigDecimal without losing format

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal, typeconverter

I'm trying to convert a string to a BigDecimal but I can't manage to preserve the format. the String is a price/number with a format which can either be #,###.00 or # ###,00

this is what i've tried but it doesn't keep the format intact. 
37,717,840.33  ==> 37717840.33

```
public static BigDecimal convertStringtoDecimal(String patternDecimalFormat, 
String pattern, String price) { 

    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(pattern.charAt(0));
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator(pattern.charAt(1));
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(patternDecimalFormat, symbols);
    decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);

    BigDecimal bigDecimal = null;
    try {
        bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(price);
    } catch (ParseException e) { 

        LOGGER.warn("Exception convertion string to dec", e);
    }
    return bigDecimal ;

}
```

Comment: `BigDecimal` doesn't format itself. It represents a _number_ not a `String`. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want to do? I see you are using `DecimalFormat` to go from a `String` to a `BigDecimal`. To reverse the operation you'd do `decimalFormat.format(bigDecimal)`. This will return a formatted `String` of the `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I have String that are in this format 37,717,840.33 or in this format 37 717 840,33 I would like to convert them to bigdecimal while preserving the format/ pattern (keeping the , and the . in place as they were in the string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is an "[i]mmutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal number[]".

What is "arbitrary-precision"? This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) has this to say in its introduction:

> In computer science, arbitrary-precision arithmetic, also called bignum arithmetic, multiple-precision arithmetic, or sometimes infinite-precision arithmetic, indicates that calculations are performed on numbers whose digits of precision are limited only by the available memory of the host system. This contrasts with the faster fixed-precision arithmetic found in most arithmetic logic unit (ALU) hardware, which typically offers between 8 and 64 bits of precision.

In other words, `BigDecimal` is a special type of `Number` that allows "perfect" (it can't handle irrational numbers) precision. This is in contrast to `Double` (or the primitive type, `double`) which has "fixed-precision" and therefore can't represent all the numbers that `BigDecimal` can. This increase in precision comes at the cost of increased memory use and much slower mathematical operations (computers can handle `double`s and such at a hardware level).

Why am I bringing all this up? Because I want to point out that a `BigDecimal` is nothing more than a *fancy number*. And numbers, at least in Java, have no concept of formatting. With that in mind you realize it makes no sense to expect a `BigDecimal` to maintain the format of the `String` used to create it. There are hints at this in your own code; you had to use the intermediary `DecimalFormat` object to parse your `String` into a `BigDecimal`. Why would you have to do this when `BigDecimal` has a constructor that takes a `String`? It's because the `BigDecimal` constructor is very limited. If you were to try to convert your `String` using the constructor you'd get a `NumberFormatExcepton` with the following message: "*Character , is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark.*"

As you can see, it is the `DecimalFormat` that understands the `String` in your code. The reason for this is because *that's what `DecimalFormat` is designed for*. The class exists so you can parse `String`s into `Number`s and `Number`s into `String`s using a specified pattern (which is normally based on the user's `Locale`). When you want to display a `Number` such as a `BigDecimal` but in a formatted fashion you have to use a class such as `DecimalFormat`. Some options to convert a number into a `String` would be:

- [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

  - Or more generally, its superclass [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)
- [`String#format(String, Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

  - This uses its own pattern rules as specified in the Javadoc of [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
- [`PrintStream#printf(String, Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

  - This uses the same rules as `String#format(String, Object...)`.
  - `System.out` is a `PrintStream`

As I pointed out in the question comments, in your case you should be able to get back the formatted `String` by calling

```
String formattedString = decimalFormat.format(bigDecimal);
```

on the same `DecimalFormat` or at least one that was configured the same.

Comment: user tries to convert string to bigdecimal.

Comment: @YannickMussche Not sure I understand your comment?

Comment: Well I got what you said and this is how I figured out my problem, but it is actually the other way around that he wanted to know. Which I found here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-bigdecimal;

Comment: The OP already knew how to convert a `String` to a `BigDecimal`, as evidenced by their code. The problem was that they wanted to "keep the format", which is impossible. In other words, they wanted to know how to print/render the number using the same format that was used when _parsing_ the string. And that is accomplished via an API such as `DecimalFormat`. That's what my answer is addressing—the misconception that the `BigDecimal` "remembers" the format. It does not; it's the `DecimalFormat` that knows the format. And a `DecimalFormat` can be used for both _parsing_ and _formatting_.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas from the string.

import java.math.BigDecimal;

---

```
    String price = "1,000,000,000.999999999999999";
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(price.replaceAll(",", ""));
    System.out.println("Prueba: " + result.toString());
```

//Result: 1000000000.999999999999999

Answer (score -1):

Remove the commas from the string.

```
String price = "1,000,000,000.999999999999999";
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(value.replaceAll(",", ""));
System.out.println(result);
```